# PayPal NVP API TransactionSearch with combined filters

Tags: api, paypal, nvp

Is it possible to apply multiple filters in a TransactionSearch request, for example in the "STATUS" option in order to retrieve both "Success" and "Reversed" transactions in a single request?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After contacting the PayPal Tech Support it seems it's not possible. Combining filters for a request is not doable so the only solutions would be either using "All" and filtering once the results were retrieved or make multiple requests per "STATUS" filter.